# error while trying to make a virtual assistant in python

Tags: python

> can someone tell me how i can fix this error I get everytime I try to run this code below

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[0].id)

# text to speech
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takecommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=1, phrase_time_limit=5)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}")


    except Exception as e:
        speak("say that again please...")
        return "none"
    return query

if __name__ == "__main__":
    takecommand()
```

> and I'm getting this error while running it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gouri/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Jarvis.py", line 33, in <module>
    takecommand()
  File "C:/Users/gouri/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Jarvis.py", line 19, in takecommand
    audio = r.listen(source, timeout=1, phrase_time_limit=5)
  File "C:\Users\gouri\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 618, in listen
    raise WaitTimeoutError("listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start")
speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError: listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

audio = r.listen(source,timeout=1,phrase_time_limit=5)

#try without timeout or set at it to atleast 5